# How are power and statistical significance related for a one-sample hypothesis test of means?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, sampling, statistical-power, critical-value

Power, in a two-sample test, is partially determined by the narrowness of the confidence interval for the test statistic the alternative hypothesis is tested over.

This is captured in this photo

[image]
via [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Statistical_test,_significance_level,_power.png)

I'm confused how power can be calculated in the case of a one-sample hypothesis test of means, where we're setting some kind of cut-point (a critical value) within the tail of a distribution, such a one-sided z or t-test.

In this case, our significance level and power seem to be interchangeable. This is the case because there is a zero probability that the mean we're testing against is anything other than what is set at the critical value.

Is this correct? Or does it not make sense to speak of power in the one-sample context at all?